# Pentaho DI6.1, Error using mBox in Email Message Input Step

Tags: pentaho, mbox

This time I need help with this software. I'm trying to create a transformation that, obtaining a mbox, return certains parts of the emails. But! When I use the step Email Message Input preview function, Pentaho return me this.

> 2016/09/09 14:52:53 - cfgbuilder - Warning: The configuration
>   parameter [org] is not supported by the default configuration builder
>   for scheme: sftp 
> 2016/09/09 14:54:58 - DBCache - Loading database
>   cache from file: [C:\Users\fangonzalez.kettle\db.cache-6.1.0.1-196]
>   
> 2016/09/09 14:54:58 - DBCache - We read 0 cached rows from the
>   database cache! 
> 2016/09/09 14:54:59 - Spoon - Trying to open the last
>   file used. 
> 2016/09/09 15:03:37 -
>   C:\Users\fangonzalez\Desktop\Pentaho\trans.ktr : trans - Dispatching
>   started for transformation
>   [C:\Users\fangonzalez\Desktop\Pentaho\trans.ktr : trans] 
> 2016/09/09
>   15:03:37 - Email messages input.0 - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build
>   1 from 
> 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : Error opening folder 1 :
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 2016/09/09 15:03:37 - Email messages
>   input.0 - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 
> 2016-04-07 12.08.49
>   by buildguy) : java.lang.NullPointerException 
> 2016/09/09 15:03:37 -
>   Email messages input.0 -  at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.mailinput.MailInput.openNextFolder(MailInput.java:347)
>   
> 2016/09/09 15:03:37 - Email messages input.0 -    at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.mailinput.MailInput.getOneRow(MailInput.java:214)
>   
> 2016/09/09 15:03:37 - Email messages input.0 -    at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.mailinput.MailInput.processRow(MailInput.java:75)
>   
> 2016/09/09 15:03:37 - Email messages input.0 -    at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62) 
> 2016/09/09
>   15:03:37 - Email messages input.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) 
> 2016/09/09 15:03:37 - Email messages input.0 - Finished
>   processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1) 
> 2016/09/09 15:03:37 -
>   C:\Users\fangonzalez\Desktop\Pentaho\trans.ktr : trans -
>   Transformation detected one or more steps with errors. 
> 2016/09/09
>   15:03:37 - C:\Users\fangonzalez\Desktop\Pentaho\trans.ktr : trans -
>   Transformation is killing the other steps!

[There is the pic of the step config screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKDcC.png)

Comment: Could you please specify exact setting (without user, password and source host) you have specified for this step? Most probably incorrect step configuration throws this NPE.

Comment: @DzmitryPrakapenka Thanks for your answer. Yes, I had the Fetch in batches option enable, and when I turned it off the step works. Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option "Fetch in batches" cannot be enable if you use only one mbox.